# VLOOKUP on AUTOFILTERED VISIBLE CELLS

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, autofilter

I am trying to vlookup for visible cells. Have 2 sheets Data (that has the required data) and Result (where I need the desired result). On the Data sheet I want to Autofilter on "sourceid" column and all that has "xtrader", I want to do a vlookup based on "entity id" and get my "source entity id" in my result sheet. similarly I want the entity id when I autofilter on "optex" as well.

Data Sheet

| entity id | source id | source entity id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | xtrader | xt-1 |
| 1002 | xtrader | xt-2 |
| 1003 | xtrader | xt-3 |
| 1004 | xtrader | xt-4 |
| 1005 | xtrader | xt-5 |
| 1006 | xtrader | xt-6 |
| 1007 | xtrader | xt-7 |
| 1008 | xtrader | xt-8 |
| 1009 | xtrader | xt-9 |
| 1010 | xtrader | xt-0 |
| 1001 | optex | op-1 |
| 1002 | optex | op-2 |
| 1003 | optex | op-3 |
| 1004 | optex | op-4 |
| 1005 | optex | op-5 |
| 1006 | optex | op-6 |
| 1007 | optex | op-7 |
| 1008 | optex | op-8 |
| 1009 | optex | op-9 |
| 1010 | optex | op-0 |

Below is my code. When I run this code, the values I get in the Result sheet are "#N/A". (I wrote this code just for getting "source entity id" based on "xtrader" only as a trial).

```
Sub Test1withvisiblecells()

    Dim sht, sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, LR As Long, LR1 As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
        
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("result")
    Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
    
    LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LR1 = sht1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    Set Rng = sht1.Range("B2:B" & LR1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      
    sht1.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="xtrader"
    With sht
        For i = 2 To LR
            Range("B" & i).Value = (Application.VLookup(sht1.Range("B2:B" & LR1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("A" & i).Value, sht1.Range("A2:C75000"), 3, False))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the result I get:

| entity id |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | #N/A |
| 1002 | #N/A |
| 1003 | #N/A |
| 1004 | #N/A |
| 1005 | #N/A |
| 1006 | #N/A |
| 1007 | #N/A |
| 1008 | #N/A |
| 1009 | #N/A |
| 1010 | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |

The result I need:

| entity id | source id - xtrader | source id - optex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | xt-1 | op-1 |
| 1002 | xt-2 | op-2 |
| 1003 | xt-3 | op-3 |
| 1004 | xt-4 | op-4 |
| 1005 | xt-5 | op-5 |
| 1006 | xt-6 | op-6 |
| 1007 | xt-7 | op-7 |
| 1008 | xt-8 | op-8 |
| 1009 | xt-9 | op-9 |
| 1010 | xt-0 | op-0 |

Answer (score 1):

Convert your data into Excel Tables, and you will discover you can do a lot more with your data. Sorry, I couldn't finish this Macro; hopefully, one of you can fix the Index Match Function, and it should be good to go.

1. Convert Data and Result Tables into Tables.
2. Use Index Match Function with Multiple Criteria.

Is there a reason you want to use VBA? You can do this using a multi-criteria Index Match function in the cell as well?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Lookup()

Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsData, wsResult, wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim Data_Table, Result_Table As ListObject
Dim source_entity_id_Range As ListObject
Dim entity_id_Index, source_id_Index, entity_id_Result_Index, entity_id_Records As Byte
Dim X As Byte
Dim entity_id_Value, source_id_Index_Value, entity_id_Result_Value As String, ResultValue As String

            Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set wsData = wbBook.Sheets("Data")
            Set wsResult = wbBook.Sheets("Result")

    'Delete Names Ranges from Named Manager
                Dim xName As Name
                For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
                    xName.Delete
                Next
                
     'Convert the ActiveSheet into an Excel Table
            For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
                    wsSheet.Activate
                    
                        Dim Src As Range
                        Dim TableName As Variant
                        Set Src = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                        TableName = wsSheet.Name
                        
                            On Error Resume Next
                                wsSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=Src, _
                                xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = TableName
                            On Error GoTo 0
            Next wsSheet
                       
        Set Data_Table = wsData.ListObjects("Data")
        Set Result_Table = wsResult.ListObjects("Result")
                    
            entity_id_Index = Data_Table.ListColumns("entity id").Index
            source_id_Index = Data_Table.ListColumns("source id").Index
            entity_id_Result_Index = Result_Table.ListColumns("entity id").Index
            
            entity_id_Records = Data_Table.ListColumns(entity_id_Index).DataBodyRange.Count
                            
            For X = 1 To entity_id_Records
                    
                    entity_id_Value = Data_Table.DataBodyRange.Cells(X, entity_id_Index).Value
                    source_id_Index_Value = Data_Table.DataBodyRange.Cells(X, source_id_Index).Value
                    
                    entity_id_Result_Value = Result_Table.DataBodyRange.Cells(X, entity_id_Index).Value
                                  
                   Set source_entity_id_Range = Data_Table.ListColumns("source entity id")
                  
                  
                   ResultValue = WorksheetFunction.Index(source_entity_id_Range _
                    , WorksheetFunction.Match(entity_id_Result_Value, _
                    Data_Table.ListColumns("entity id").Range, 0))

            'Use a Multiple Criteria Index Match Function

             
             Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. I have just pasted only a portion of my file. This file has data more than 30000 rows and i need to run this report on a daily basis. Hence i prefer to have a macro.

Answer (score 0):

When applying a `formula` there is not need to loop over the cells, just build the appropriated formula and "write" it into the cells, then overwrite the formulas with their return value.

This code builds a `FormulaArray` and applies it to the output range in the Results sheet

*Note: The code contains two debugging lines to validate the output range in the `Results` worksheet, delete these lines after the procedure is final.*

```
Sub Get_SourceId()
Const kFml As String = "= IFERROR( INDEX( #COL3, MATCH( #ENT & ""#WHAT"", #COL1 & #COL2, 0 ) ), TEXT(,) )"  'Formula template
Dim aWhats As Variant
aWhats = [{"xtrader","optex"}]                                                  'Source IDs
Dim WsData As Worksheet, WsResult As Worksheet
Dim sFml As String, sWhat As String
Dim lRow As Long, b As Byte
        
    Rem Set Objects
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WsData = .Worksheets("data")
        Set WsResult = .Worksheets("result")
        lRow = WsResult.Cells(WsResult.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
                
    Rem Set Formula - Data Worksheet part
    sFml = kFml
    With WsData.UsedRange
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#COL1", .Columns(1).Address(External:=True))
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#COL2", .Columns(2).Address(External:=True))
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "#COL3", .Columns(3).Address(External:=True))
        sFml = Replace(sFml, "[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]", vbNullString)       'Removes Workbook name to avoid a Formula lenght > 255 characters
    End With
    
    With WsResult.Cells(2, 1).Resize(-1 + lRow, 3)

            Rem Set Formula - Results Worksheet part
            sFml = Replace(sFml, "#ENT", .Columns(1).Address(0, 0))
            For b = 1 To UBound(aWhats)
                    
                Rem Set Formula - Results Worksheet Variable part
                sWhat = Replace(sFml, "#WHAT", aWhats(b))
                
                With .Columns(1 + b)
: Application.Goto WsResult.Cells(1), 1    'Included for debugging purposes - [Remove after procedure is final]
: .Select: Stop                            'Included for debugging purposes - Validates the length of the output range [Remove after procedure is final]
                    
                    Rem Apply FormulaArray
                    .FormulaArray = sWhat
                    .Value = .Value
        
    End With: Next: End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ EEM - This is not stopping with the last row in the result sheet. even for the blank rows in result sheet, i get "#N/A"

Comment: `This is not stopping with the last row in the result sheet` _Procedure adjusted to utilize the `last row` based on `Column A`_. `for the blank rows in result sheet, i get "#N/A` _IFERROR added to the formula_. Please test adjusted procedure.

Comment: As mentioned before the formulas will look for only cells that comply with the criteria `ID` & `Source entity` which is the same criteria you are using for the `.AutoFilter` and the `Vlookup`. Would you please explain your reasons for persisting with the `.AutoFilter`?

Comment: @ EEM - getting an error at .SELECT: STOP. Since I thought that Vlookup on autofilter cells would be easier i was persisting on that. As long as i have the desired result am ok with any logic.

Comment: what error, hard to do anything with out that info.

Comment: what about the line above . did you commented it?

Comment: It worked. will test on my bigger file and let you know if i have any issues. Appreciate all your help. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230199/discussion-between-eem-and-user2574).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have sheets like these:

[image: sheet data] [image]

This is the result you would get after running the code below:

[image]

```
Sub Test1withvisiblecells()

  Dim sht As Worksheet, sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Rng As Range, a As Range, c As Range
  Dim curr_row_found As Boolean
  
  Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("result")
  Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
  
  Set Rng = Intersect(sht1.Range("A:A"), _
                      sht1.UsedRange.Offset(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
  
  For i = 2 To sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    curr_row_found = False
    For Each a In Rng.Areas
      For Each c In a
        If sht.Range("A" & i) = c Then
          Select Case c.Offset(, 1)
          Case "xtrader": sht.Range("B" & i) = c.Offset(, 2)
          Case "optex": sht.Range("C" & i) = c.Offset(, 2)
          Case Else: 'pass
          End Select
          curr_row_found = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If curr_row_found Then Exit For
    Next
  Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: The result sheet cannot be empty. I already have the entity ID in there and only for those IDs, i need the source entity id, which has "xtrader" as the value. basically am doing a lookup for "entity id" on visible cells and getting my "source entity id"

Comment: can some one help me to do a vookup on the visible cells please ? thanks

Comment: this  code brings in either or value. is there a way that i get both the values in 2 different columns ?

Comment: It brings both, if it is  visible, as you wanted.